# Creating a Two Dimensional ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on a school project that requires (or at least strongly suggests) using two dimensional ArrayLists in Java (specifically an ArrayList that holds ArrayList of `int`s). I don't find the syntax too hard to grasp, but the below code has really stumped me:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();
arrList1D.add(1);
arrList2D.add(arrList1D);
```

That snippet gives me the error:

```
Cannot convert List<Integer> to ArrayList<Integer>
```

on the very last line. What I find confusing is that I explicitly instantiate `arrList1D` as an ArrayList. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Would definitely appreciate any help with this. Sorry for any redundant questions.

Comment: Try declare as `List<List<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2):

`List<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();`

While you are creating a new `ArrayList` Object of type `Integer`, you use a `List` variable to reference the Object. As far as the compiler knows, the Object `arrList1D` is referencing is a List, not ArrayList. ArrayList *extends* List, such that every `ArrayList` is a `List`, but not every `List` is an `ArrayList`. The error comes when you try add a `List` Object to a List that only accepts `ArrayList` Objects [More on Java Inheritance.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

You will need to instead ensure `arrList1D` is referenced by an `ArrayList` variable OR the type of the '2D List' is List, not ArrayList.

```
List<List<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();
arrList1D.add(1);
arrList2D.add(arrList1D);
```

or

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();
arrList1D.add(1);
arrList2D.add(arrList1D);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the error you are seeing is because arrList1D is of type `List` meaning it can be any List implementation (though in your case you have chosen ArrayList).

Where as your arrList2D is Declared as `List<ArrayList<Integer>>` The inner list in this case has to explicitly be of type ArrayList.

There are two ways to make this compile either change the type of arrList1D to be an ArrayList

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();
    arrList1D.add(1);
    arrList2D.add(arrList1D);
```

Or change the inner type of arrList2D to use List.

```
    List<List<Integer>> arrList2D = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> arrList1D = new ArrayList<>();
    arrList1D.add(1);
    arrList2D.add(arrList1D);
```

I would recommend using the second option as it gives you the flexibility to change either the inner or outer List implementations freely.